# Redirected after an "it" statement when using Capybara and RSPEC

Tags: rspec, capybara

I currently have a problem with my integration tests in which I fill out a form in a before clause, clicking the submit button.  I then use

```
it "has ..." do end
```

to check if the redirected path is correct, which it is.  However, upon completion of the first "it" statement, I am redirected to a different page, and the several consecutive "it" statements fail because I am no longer on the page.

Here is a sample code snippet.

```
...
context "when the correct information is entered" do
    before {
        fill_in 'Email', :with => 'test@test.test'
        fill_in 'Username', :with => 'some_user'
        fill_in 'Password', :with => 'Password'
        fill_in 'Password Confirmation', :with => 'Password'
        select 'foo', :from => 'user_type'
        click_button 'Save'
    }
    it "has valid html" do
        page.should have_valid_html
    end
    it "has current_path users/2" do
        current_path.should == users_path+'/2'
    end
...
```

So, here, the "has valid html" test passes, but the second test fails because I am redirected to 'users' instead of staying on 'users/2'.  Likewise, if I switch the order of the 'it' statements, I get the same result.

Should I be doing my "before" differently or is there something else I need to consider?

Thanks for helping,
boka

Edit:  A corollary bit of information; I've done nearly the exact same thing in other parts of the code, except without the select field.  If it worked in all other cases, might that be the problem?

Comment: If the path is supposed to be `users/2` and it isn't, you need to figure out what is causing that. RSpec is merely telling you that the expectation has failed -- which it has.

Comment: The path is 'users/2' when I do the "has valid html" test
It changes to 'users' after completing the first "it"

Would this have something to do with the lazy calls?

Comment: No, the two examples execute in separate contexts -- the before block runs before each one. The path that you end up on should be the same for each example. You might try looking in log/test.log to see where the redirects are occurring.

Comment: Is it possible that the object is not being cleared from the database between each call to "before" because of the deactivated transactional fixtures?  In that case, it would just have been a failure redirect back to the users page.

Comment: On second though, don't waste your time by answering that, I'll check it myself :)

Comment: And... Yes, that was the problem.  I will fix this by adding
    after {
        (delete user)
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Capybara, it is important to remember that transactional fixtures do not work.  In other words, RSPEC usually "rolls back" any changes made to the database during testing (in this case, after each "it" statement).  However, when using Capybara, you must either manually delete elements, or truncate the database with a tool like Database Cleaner.

This is important here, because my database handles only one user per email.

Edit:

My fix was to call User.delete on the last user in the index.  Keep in mind, however, that the index is not reset and that the next user created will increment the index from the same point.

Beware, contexts might be rolled back, while it's are not.